# Rendering a WinForm window to a SlimDX Device

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, overlay, slimdx

I have lately been working on an overlay program and now I've been trying to find a good way to design my overlay as a Windows Form, then just programatically add in the the right information into an instance of this form and finally send it over to an injected Dll that should then display this Form instance through the SlimDX Device of the game.

I thought about rendering the Form to an Image object and then displaying this through the Device, but this doesnt allow for stuff like simple animations of the overlay since its not fast enough in terms of performance to do it with a considerable framerate.

So what I am asking is, is there a more efficient way to do this?
Maybe a way to directly render a WinForm or a WPF Form (since it's DX-based) to a SlimDX/DirectX device ?

Comment: Why don't you try the opposite? Rendering DirectX content to a WinForms window is not a problem, and then adding WinForms items (buttons, etc) on top of that works, too.

Comment: Well, because thats not what I am trying to do, I am trying to render this Form ontop of a game, by rendering it to its DirectX device.